# Can I use my own request on random API's from web

Tags: reactjs, rest, redux, axios

I'm currently doing my CRUD app using react+redux and I wanted to ask you, if f.e. I use this API:

```
https://breakingbadapi.com/documentation
```

which supports only GET request, I can somehow manage to use POST request to add some new characters, or EDIT some data? or do I have to find an API which supports all kind of requests?

Comment: You can only use what an API supports if it's not your API, by definition.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Why do you need to change their data? Just get data and add your data to existing response data.

Comment: @Rakesh I wanna make a project with all CRUD requests. I did it once with fakestoreapi, where i can add products, delete them etc. And i was wondering if i can do it locally with some other random APIs from internet.

Comment: @personOfIdNull, then it completely depends on that API, if they allow then only you can do it. Check their docs

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. An external API (e.g., one you don't control) is *external*, you can only use what it supports. An API *you* control can do whatever you want it to, including using an external API, but you can't make an *external* API do what *you* want, because it's not controlled by you.